# How shall i create a NIC in AzureRM using powershell with same configuration (Vnet, Subnet) as of other VM in same RG

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I am writing a script to clone a VM(unmanaged to unmanaged disk) in Azure, i want to know how to create NEW NIC using existing VM NIC config(same VNet,Subnet) in the same RG.

Comment: Well, Do you just want to New NIC have same Subnet in the same RG?

Comment: yes but i want the subnet and RG to be fetched from source VM NIC subnet and RG

Comment: You can check my answer and be free to update here.

Comment: am unable to store values in $subnet = $oldnic.nic.IpConfigurations.subnet attaching my error details. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRk5g.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRk5g.png

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, it should be `$subnet.id`. NOT `$subnet` .I have updated my answer. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create w new NIC with the same SubNet and VNet as the an old NIc in the same Resource Group.

You can use the following powershell scripts :

```
$destinationResourceGroup = <yourRGName>
$location = <thedestinationlocation>
$oldnic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $destinationResourceGroup -Name <theOldNICName>
$subnet = $oldnic.nic.IpConfigurations.subnet
$newnic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name <newnicName> -ResourceGroupName $destinationResourceGroup -Location $location  -SubnetId $subnet.Id
```

If you can also  associate other resources to the new NIC (One IPaddress can only associate to one NIC)

```
$newnic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name <newnicName> -ResourceGroupName $destinationResourceGroup -Location $location -SubnetId $subnet.Id    -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id
```

**Additonal:** You may want to use `-IpConfiguration $oldnic.IpConfigurations` to copy the same Ipconfiguration, but you would came across one issue about the associated IP address.

So, If you just want to copy a NIC, you'd better not use this command. But if you can deallocate the IPaddress after getting the Ipconfigurations of the old NIC, you can use it.

Hope this helps!